# How do I set permissions on directory(folder) on IIS 6.0?

Tags: php, iis, permissions, file-permissions, image-uploading

I am trying to set permissions on uploads folder. I have two projects - an original project and a pilot project. I am trying to upload images from php code. It works for me for the original project but it does not work for the pilot project where I am testing some functionality.

For "uploads" folder in original project:
I see "full control" "modify" "write" in permissions settings have black ticks and everything else has grey ticks in front of them.

For "uploads" folder in pilot project:
All the ticks are grey. And I tried to edit those permissions for IIS Users 1000 times, but it didn't reflect.

I have been searching for the solution since two weeks and I tried most of the solutions I found online but didn't work for me. I am new to IIS server and PHP. Some of the answers suggested that we have to change some settings in IIS manager. Please let me know if anyone needs any additional information. Thanks!

Comment: This site is about programming, not server configuration. You might have better luck at http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com

Comment: I Got This Link This Will Be useful for you : http://www.apdsoft.com/afo/iis6.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gray -- mean they inherited from parent folder.

Go to folder property -> Security -> Advanced -> Change permissions -> check on "Replace all child object.....". -> click Apply and OK for close folder property.

Report folder property -> Security -> make sure that user which are running your Web Pool has WRITE permission

[image]